# Add TodayDate function to the history of today app

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I'm making a history of today app in IOS.

the code is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class HistoryAPICaller {
    
    static let shared = HistoryAPICaller()
    
    struct Constants
    {
        static let topHeadLinesURL = URL(string:"http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/6/3")
        
        static let searchUrlString = "http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/6/3"
    }
    
    private init() {}
    
    public func getTopStories(completion: @escaping (Result<[Events], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let html = Constants.topHeadLinesURL else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: html) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(HistoryAPIResponse.self, from: data)
                    
                    print("Articles: \(result.data.Events.count)")
                    
                    completion(.success(result.data.Events))
                }
                catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    public func search(with query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Events], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        guard !query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        let urltring = Constants.searchUrlString + query
        guard let html = URL(string:urltring) else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: html) { data, _, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion ( .failure(error))
            }
            else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(HistoryAPIResponse.self, from: data)
                    
                    print("Articles: \(result.data.Events.count)")
                    
                    completion(.success(result.data.Events))
                }
                catch {
                    completion (.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct HistoryAPIResponse: Codable  {
    let data: HistoryDataAPIResponse }

struct HistoryDataAPIResponse: Codable  {
    let Events: [Events]
}

struct Events: Codable {
    let year: String
    let text: String
    let html: String
    let no_year_html: String
    let links: [Links]
}

struct Links: Codable {
    let link: String
}
```

Now I want to add the current date function to the code, so instead of constantly showing the historic event of June 3rd
"http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/6/3"  ,
it will be something like

"http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/(currentMonth)/(currentDay)"

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dateComponents` method to retrieve the current day and month, define this function is your `HistoryAPICaller` class:

```
func getSearchUrlString() -> String 
{
    let dayAndMonth = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: Date())

    guard let day = dayAndMonth.day, let month = dayAndMonth.month else { return "" }
    
    return "http://history.muffinlabs.com/date/\(month)/\(day)"
}
```

Then edit your `search` method to retrieve the URL from it:

```
public func search(with query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Events], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        guard !query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        let urltring = getSearchUrlString() + query
        guard let html = URL(string:urltring) else {
            return
        }
    ...
```

Comment: Cannot find 'searchUrlString' in scope